# Visual Studio 2013 Update 1 with WIndows 8.1 Pro update 1 unable connecting to TFS

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, team-explorer

I have vs2013 Update 1 installed on my Laptop Windows 8.1 Pro Update 1 and the server using tfs 2012. I can access tfs from browser but when I want to connect to tfs from Team Explorer I got this error message:

> TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server:  `http://ServerIpAddress:8080/tfs`.
>   
> Possible reasons for failure include:
>   
> - The name, port number, or protocol for the Team Foundation Server is incorrect.
>   
> - The Team Foundation Server is offline.
>   
> - The password has expired or is incorrect.
>   
>   
>   For further information, contact the Team Foundation Server administrator.

I've try :

- [How to: Change the BypassProxyOnLocal Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb909716.aspx)

- Turn off Firewall on my laptop


 Can anyone fix this issue..?

Thanks before

Comment: There _have_ been issues with TFS and McAfee, could that be an issue here?

Comment: I have no McAfee on my laptop, the only antivirus on my laptop is win defender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve my issue by deleting folder TokenStorage registry in ***HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSCommon\12.0\ClientServices\TokenStorage***

Thanks you all.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following? In the "Connect to Team Foundation Server" window, hit the "Servers" Button and then try to delete the corrupted server connection. Consequently re-define the server connection once again.